# Add a grid on figures for trimming purpose (by redefining \includegraphics)

Tags: grids, overpic

I need to (temporarly) redefine `\includegraphics` command for trimming purposes. This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[abs]{overpic}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\resizebox*{1\textwidth}{!}{\begin{overpic}[grid,unit=1pt]{lemon.jpg}
\end{overpic}}\relax

\includegraphics[trim = 0 100 0 100, clip, width=1\textwidth]{lemon.jpg}
\caption{\label{myfig}My caption.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In this example I have a picture inserted with the `overpic` environment that create a grid on my figure. This allow my to find, quickly, the values to pass to the `trim` parameter of the `\includegraphics` command.

To make this operation much less "overkill" I tried to redefine the `\includegraphics` command this way:

```
\renewcommand*{\includegraphics}[2][]{\resizebox*{1\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{overpic}[grid,unit=1pt]{#2}\end{overpic}}\relax}
```

but it doesn't work. I get this error:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255]....
```

I know you may find it yet "overkill" but I have my goog reasons to do that.(This would allow me to pass this redefinition by command line, keeping my `.tex` untouched)

My answer(s) is "how can I redefine the `\includegraphics` command to insert this sort of grid in my figures? What's wrong in my code?"

I took the idea from this post: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7783

**Edit**. I can't understand why if i define this command(s)

```
\newcommand{\vacua}[1]{}
\newcommand*{\myincludegraphics}[2][]{\resizebox*{1\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{overpic}[grid,unit=1pt]{#2}\end{overpic}}\relax\vacua{#1}}
```

the string:

```
\myincludegraphics[trim = 0 100 0 100, clip, width=1\textwidth]{lemon.jpg}
```

generates my picture with the grid correctly. But if i do:

```
\newcommand{\myignore}[1]{}
\let\includegraphics\undefined %% I undefine "\includegraphics"
\newcommand*{includegraphics}[2][]{\resizebox*{1\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{overpic}[grid,unit=1pt]{#2}\end{overpic}}\relax\myignore{#1}}
```

with the string:

```
\includegraphics[trim = 0 100 0 100, clip, width=1\textwidth]{lemon.jpg}
```

I keek getting the same error.

Comment: Circular definition, overpic uses includegraphics internally. You're better of making a personal macro and then replacing it when you are done trimming.

Comment: Again circular definition. Overpic uses includegraphics internally, so you get includegrapgics, calling overpic, calling includegrapgics, calling overpic....

Comment: Your myincludegraphics is a bit strange. Why are you throwing away the optional argument (#1). Instead of passing it on to overpic?

Comment: There is another possibility with tikz: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559/138900

Comment: @daleif If I pass it to overpic I'll get wrong values... look at https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7783

Comment: Did you remember to use `[grid,unit=1pt,#1]`, not i do not remember if overpic passes args onto includegraphics like this, it should be in the manual. Not at pc so cannot help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid the circular definition (as pointed by [daleif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3929/daleif)) I solved using this trick:

1. I replace "\includegraphics" with "\myincludegraphics" in my .tex (easy to do with `emacs`)
2. I compile with these options:

   ```
   pdflatex '\AtBeginDocument{\RequirePackage[abs]{overpic}\newcommand{\myignore}\[1]{} \newcommand*{\myincludegraphics}\[2][]{\resizebox*{1\textwidth}{!}{\begin{overpic}[grid,unit=1pt]{#2}\end{overpic}}\relax\myignore{#1}}} \nonstopmode\input{myfile.tex}'
   ```

   Now I get a grid on all the picture inserted with the `\includegraphics` command and I can use the `trim` parameter to tune the layout having a visible estimation of the trimming values (expressed in pt).
3. I restore the `\includegraphics` string in my `.tex` file.

The `\resizebox` stuff helps me to obtain a temporarly enlarged layout of the figures...

The `\myignore` trick is required to obtain a real estimation of the trimming values (see https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7783)

I wrote a short `elisp` function that does all these operations (points 1-3) in one shot (I love `emacs`).

Comment: DON'T use `src-specials`. They disrupt the typesetting for no purpose whatsoever.

Comment: @egreg I removed the `src-specials` stuff. It's not relevant in this case.